# Does my hosting provider have an impact on my website loading speed?

Tags: web-hosting, performance, page-speed, shared-hosting

My website size is around 3.3 MB and takes 7 seconds to load!

My hosting provider is some `x.com` and my nameservers are `yz.webhostbox.net`. Do I need to have the nameservers from my hosting company?

Where am I possibly going wrong?

My website is on shared hosting. But 7 seconds is very long.

Comment: "3.3 mb" - I assumed you meant "MB"? What kind of a website is this? Static HTML? Blog? PHP? .NET? Are you using some kind of CMS? +Plugins? Much traffic? Are you searching for extraterrestrial life??

Comment: @w3dk I was a consultant to a global telecom that is famous for their phone booths. There was one manager who wanted to have a dominant presence in the development and production NOCs to boost his ego. So he bought hundreds of servers for various projects where new servers were not needed. The idea was to take up space in the NOCs to boost the notion of his importance. But they had nothing to do. So I set them up to run the SETI client. All 200 of them. We went from last to #1 in two weeks. We beat a Cray running for years! We ***were*** searching for ETs. Damned the torpedos!

Comment: 7 seconds is too long. I would be looking at what you may be doing that is not working efficiently. If you are sure that your site should perform okay, then I would say look at your host. There are different qualities of hosts from extremely poor to extremely good. If you can, test your site locally on an old PC you have laying around. That way, you can know if you need to improve your site or if your site is good.

Answer (score 3):

> Does my hosting provider have an impact on my website loading speed?

It can have, but that's *probably* not the main cause in this instance.

> Does it need to have the nameservers from my hosting company?

No.

> Where am I possibly going wrong?

The million dollar question, with a million (approx) possible answers.

If you've ruled out that it's not the network between you and your website then it could literally be anything to do with your website. Is your site doing anything particularly taxing?

- How does the site perform on your development server?
- Too many/conflicting plugins on a WordPress install is a common one (but also, incredibly broad).
- You can make improvements with client/server-side caching and compression. But that's only an "optimisation". You still need to cut the load time by half - at least.

Answer (score 1):

Since before a browser can download a website it needs to resolve the domain name, slow nameservers can be a problem. It doesn't matter whether you use the same provider for DNS and website though.

Your hosting provider most likely has a lot more impact on your website loading speed. Of course if your site is larger it will load slower but there can be are huge differences between providers.

But even if your provider is fast, if it's not including a CDN it can be still very slow to users far away from the physical location of the provider's servers. This is how response times looked for mail.live.com:
[image] (take some time last week).

As you can see, even though the response times are good in New York, they are really bad in Singapore.